# Delphi Forms Z-Order problema extraño

Tags: windows, modal, delphi, active

Esta es una pregunta de Delphi7, el problema se muestra en WinXP y Win7.
Realmente estoy atascado con un comportamiento extraño relacionado con Z-Order de Delphi-Forms.
Intenté casi todo que se describe mas abajo y pasé demasiado tiempo buscando en muchas comunidades...

Aquí mi objetivo:
Tengo un formulario (formDoc) para mostrar el manual de mi prog presionando F1 desde cualquier parte de mi prog, realizado con el
Componente ApplicationEvents, y también muchos formularios modales.
Quiero poder tener ese formDoc abierto o minimizado todo el tiempo para llevar al usuario a la
parte específica del manual presionando F1.
¡Hasta aquí todo funciona bien!

El problema comienza cuando formDoc se ha abierto desde el formulario principal, luego, después de abrir cualquiera de los formularios modales y presionar F1 nuevamente, formDoc se vuelve inactivo (no se mueve, no se cierra, nada ... parece que
permanece detrás de la forma modal, pero es resaltado como activo y también se superpone a la forma modal).

¡Pero solo en este caso! Cuando formDoc se cierra ANTES de abrir cualquier formulario modal y luego presionar F1 para abrirlo, todo está bien.

Así que mi conclusión fue que esto debe estar relacionado con el Orden Z de las formas.
Intenté lo siguiente:
·SetForegroundWindow
·SetWindowPos con todas las flags posibles
·SetActiveWindow
·Todo GetLastError da OK
·Capturar el evento ActiveFormChanged para cerrar formDoc allí antes de volver a abrir con F1
·Cerrar formDoc en ApplicationEvents y volver a mostrarlo
No hay manera cerrando formDoc por código (Se cierra pero el problema persiste).
La única forma ahora es cerrar FormDoc manualmente antes de mostrar cualquier otra forma y presionar F1
para reabrirlo, pero esto no es aceptable..

¿Por qué sucede eso? estoy realmente atascado..
Necesito ayuda

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. El idioma oficial es español, así que debo pedirte que traduzcas toooooooooooooda la pregunta (incluyendo el título!) 
para que otros te respondan y para que no termine cerrada. 
Recuerda que puedes [edit] la pregunta todas las veces que quieras.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). Una buena pregunta siempre termina reabierta :)

Comment: ¿Qué ocurre si pones al formulario el ```FormStyle = fsStayOnTop```?

Comment: @jachguate El FormStyle no cambia nada, ya lo he probado.

Comment: @jachguate Recuerdo, solo se produce el problema cuando formDoc está abierto antes de abrir culaquier form modal y presionar F1. Cuando se abre un form modal con formdoc cerrado y  después F1, todo va bien...

Comment: Una _solución_ sencilla podría ser, si ya está creado el formulario al ser invocado desde un form modal, destruirlo y volver a crearlo. ¿has considerado esa opción?

Comment: @jachguate Gracias, pero no es una opción. Mantengo un historial en el formdoc para saltar atrás y adelante y también entre documentos, que se perdería así.  Puedo conseguir lo mismo cerrando formDoc en cada evento Clic de los botones para abrir

Comment: ...los forms modales. Esto si funciona curiosamente! He encontrado una solución que  publicaré en breve.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una solución para mi problema aunque sigo sin entender lo que pasa  detrás del telón de Windows. Agradecería si alguien con conocimientos mas  profundos me iluminaría un poco..

En un foro que por desgrácia no me acuerdo (era tarde y cerró el compi sin pensar)
alguien recomendó deshabilitar el formDoc antes de mostrarlo y volver a habilitarlo.
El tema no trataba del mismo problema, sino de forms modales escondidos detrás
de otros modales en ocasiones.

No me parecía tener sentido, pero la desesperación me llevaba a probarlo...

Así aquí va el código del ApplicationEvents con la 'Mágia' que resuelve el problema extraño:

```
 if (Msg.message = WM_KEYDOWN)and (Msg.wParam = VK_F1) then
  begin
    case idioma of
    1: manualpath:= exedir+'docs\Manual español.html';
    2: manualpath:= exedir+'docs\Handbuch deutsch.html';
    3: manualpath:= exedir+'docs\Manual english.html';
    end;
    if wideFileExists(manualpath) then
    begin
      st:= TTntMemorystream.Create;
      screen.Cursor:=crHourglass;
      try
        handled:= true;
        st.LoadFromFile(manualpath);
        formdoc.Viewer.LoadFromStream(st,manualpath);
        formdoc.Viewer.PositionTo(GetManualTopic);
        formdoc.Caption:= formdoc.Viewer.DocumentTitle;
        ShowWindow(FormDoc.Handle, SW_RESTORE); //para restaurar cuando minimizado
        formdoc.Enabled:= false;   /////Eso cambia todo..
        try
          formdoc.Show;
          FormDoc.UpdateDocPos;   ///función interna
        finally
          formdoc.Enabled:= true;
        end;
      finally
        st.Free;
        screen.Cursor:=crDefault;
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      handled:= true;
      MyMessageDlg(docnotfound+#13#10+#13#10+manualpath,mtWarning,[mbOk],[mOk], info,mbOk);
    end;
  end;
```

Ahora todo funciona como esperado, formDoc se puede tener siempre abierto o
minimizado, se abre o será restaurado siempre correctamente con F1 y se superpone
sobre cualquier form modal también cuando hay varios modales superpuestos.
Comprobado en XP, Win7 y Win10.

Espero que sea de ayuda para otros que experimentan lo mismo.

¿Pero, que está pasando realmente detrás?
¿Alguien es capaz de iluminarme?

Muchas gracias!